# ANT <mxmlc> task failing when using AIR sdk (compiler.jar does not exist)

Tags: ant, build, air

I have a project that was built in FlashDevelop. It is not an AIR application, but because we are using Starling we are compiling with the AIR sdk (v14). Running the project from FlashDevelop is working fine. I'm working on an ANT script that will eventually be used in Hudson. I am getting the following error when running the script:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\project\client\build.xml:50: File does not exist: compiler.jar

    at com.adobe.flash.compiler.ant.FlexTask.resolveClass(FlexTask.java:404)
       at com.adobe.flash.compiler.ant.FlexTask.executeInProcess(FlexTask.java:
300)
        at com.adobe.flash.compiler.ant.FlexTask.execute(FlexTask.java:260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Here is the ANT script

```
<project name="Flex Ant Build Script" default="init">


<property environment="env"/>
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="${env.FLEX_HOME}" />
<property name="AIRSDK_HOME" value="C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/FlashDevelop/Apps/ascsdk/14.0.0" />


<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${AIRSDK_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar"/> 

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-contrib-0.6.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="init">
    <property name="INPUT_FILE_NAME" value="Main.as"/>
    <property name="OUTPUT_FILE_NAME" value="Main"/>
    <property name="OUTPUT_FILE_EXT" value="swf"/>
    <property name="SRC_DIR" value="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="OUTPUT_FOLDER" value="${basedir}/deploy"/>

    <property name="DEBUG" value="false"/>
    <property name="OPTIMIZE" value="true"/>
    <property name="LOCALE" value="en_US"/>
    <property name="STATIC_LINK" value="true"/>
    <property name="STRICT" value="false"/>
    <property name="WARNINGS" value="false"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="init">
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${OUTPUT_FOLDER}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>   
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <echo>output = ${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}.${OUTPUT_FILE_EXT}</echo>
    <echo>${AIRSDK_HOME}</echo>
    <property name="AIR_LIB" value="C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/FlashDevelop/Apps/ascsdk/14.0.0/frameworks/libs/air"/>
    <mxmlc  file="${SRC_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_NAME}" 
            output="${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}.${OUTPUT_FILE_EXT}"        
            debug="${DEBUG}"
            optimize="${OPTIMIZE}"
            locale="${LOCALE}"
            static-rsls="${STATIC_LINK}"
            strict="${STRICT}"
            warnings="${WARNINGS}">                 

        <library-path dir="${AIRSDK_HOME}" includes="asc-support.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${AIRSDK_HOME}" includes="core.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${AIR_LIB}" includes="aircore.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${AIR_LIB}" includes="applicationupdater.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${AIR_LIB}" includes="applicationupdater_ui.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${AIR_LIB}" includes="servicemonitor.swc" append="true"/>


    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

I've dug through the FlexTasks.jar for both Flex and AIR and they are considerably different (as they should be).  I've tried moving the FlexTasks.jar from each ant/lib to ${ANT_HOME}/lib and that didn't work (as I've read in other posts).  And now I'm at a total impasse as I'm relatively new ANT.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Oh and compiler.jar is in the 'lib' folder under the AIR sdk

Answer (score 1):

The ant `<mxmlc>` task is poorly documented, behaves differently than the CLI version of `mxmlc` command, and the AIRSDK does not come with `mxmlc.jar` required for for the task.

I had given up on it, despite trying to do it several times.

Use the command line version, through ANT. I've used your property names in the code below.

```xml
<property name="mxmlc.jar" value="${AIRSDK_HOME}/lib/mxmlc-cli.jar"/>
<!-- ${FLEX_SDK}/lib/mxmlc.jar is not used, has issues with AIR related projects -->
<!-- <mxmlc> task is not used, poorly documented and behaves differently than cli -->
<!-- also, AIRSDK does not come with mxmlc.jar required for <mxmlc> task -->

<!-- Prepare command line -->
<property name="argline_compileBuildType" 
         value="-debug=${DEBUG} -optimize=${OPTIMIZE}"/>
<property name="argline_compileConfig" 
         value="+flexlib='${AIRSDK_HOME}/frameworks'"/>
<property name="argline_compileFiles" 
         value="-output=${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}.${OUTPUT_FILE_EXT} ${SRC_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_NAME}"/>
<property name="argline_compileLibPath" 
         value="-library-path+=${AIRSDK_HOME}/asc-support.swc -library-path+=${AIR_LIB}/aircore.swc "/>

<!-- Show command line arguments and execute -->
<echo message="Executing: ${argline_compileBuildType} ${argline_compileConfig} ${argline_compileFiles} ${argline_compileLibPath}"/> 
<java jar="${mxmlc.jar}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="${argline_compileBuildType}"/>
        <arg line="${argline_compileConfig}"/>
        <arg line="${argline_compileFiles}"/>
        <arg line="${argline_compileLibPath}"/>
    </java>
```

Refer to the **[following reference for more command line options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)**, for things such as your `${LOCALE}` and `${STATIC_LINK}`